# Dashboards - (dial) meters in R

Tags: r, dashboard

I'm wondering if it is possible to do this kind of dashboards in R (I mean this kind of plots)?

Here is examples which I want to do in R  (first is from `SAS`)

**edit**: i work on Windows 7 (64bit).

[image]

[image]

Comment: Are you looking for something that immediately provides you with this or are you willing to put some work into it?

Comment: Maybe both, if i have something to start to work on, but if there is a way to do that faster i would be grateful.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Here is something to start with using base graphics. Making it prettier is left to the reader. You can see an example in action here: http://www.math.csi.cuny.edu/gw/ex-dashboard.R .

```
dashboard <- function(dial=list(
                        list(color="red",
                             range=c(10, 40)),
                        list(color="yellow",
                             range=c(40, 60)),
                        list(color="green",
                             range=c(70, 100))
                        ),
                      value=from) {


  from <- min(unlist(lapply(dial, "[[", i="range")))
  to <-  max(unlist(lapply(dial, "[[", i="range")))

  theta <- seq(-pi/3, pi + pi/3, length=100)
  r <- 1

  scale <- function(x) {
    m <- (pi + pi/3 - (-pi/3))/(from - to)
    (pi + pi/3) + m*(x - from)
  }

  plot.new()
  plot.window(xlim=c(-1, 1), ylim=c(sin(-pi/3), 1))

  lines(cos(theta), sin(theta))
  sapply(dial, function(l) {
    d <- scale(l$range)
    x <- seq(d[1], d[2], length=100)
    lines(cos(x), sin(x), col=l$color, lwd=3)
  })

  ticks <- pretty(c(from, to), n=5)
  ticks_th <- scale(ticks)
  r <- 1 - .15
  text(r*cos(ticks_th), r*sin(ticks_th), labels=ticks)

  sapply(ticks_th, function(th) {
    lines(cos(th)*c(1,.95), sin(th)*c(1, .95))
  })

  r <- 1 - .25
  th <- scale(value)
  arrows(0, 0, cos(th), sin(th))


}

dashboard( value=60)
```

Comment: Great function! I am not used to thinking in circles, cos, sin, etc... Is it easy to change this graph to half a circle (top half) where the left is 0 and the right is 100?

Answer (score 5):

You can do something similar with polar plots:

```
require(plotrix)
polar.plot( c(0,20),c(0,60),main="Dashboard",lwd=3,line.col=4)
```

You can dig deeper into the code if you want to customize the look.  Using `radial.plot` may give you more customization.

[image: polar plot]

Answer (score 2):

This has little to do with R, but only with *how to get hold of GUI widgets representing dashboard items*.

I think Gtk2 may do that, so the RGtk2 package (and its wrappers) could be of help. I know for a fact that the Qwt toolkit has, but that one is more difficult to access (as you need a C++ bridge).

Comment: So there's no possible way to plot such meters in R? Well I don't need a gui but a similar figures/plots.

Comment: I didn't say that it was not possible. I did say that it isn't built in.  I know that Qwt toolkit (for C++, built on top of Qt) has it.  But that is not easy to get to (but possible).  It depends on many things such as platform, OS, ... none of which you stated.